# Accordion menu on mobile viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created an page with multiple accordions, I'm having a lot of issues with making it mobile compatible. What I want it to do is as the size decreases, the accordions start compacting into a single row. I've tried using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

But It seemed to make it worse. What's the best way of going about this?

Heres my codepen - http://codepen.io/Ahhmmogh/pen/ZGxLmo

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the specific CSS/JS you're using to try to compact into a single row?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some CSS to get this done, and for that you need [Media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) in your CSS :

```
> /*Select your break point*/
>     @media (max-width: 500px) {
>       /*Make the elements fit with the whole width */
>       .container {
>         min-width:100% !important;
>       }
>       .whole-body{
>         min-width:100% !important;
>       }
>     }
```

Working: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3zdz5ca/) .

Note that: the main mission of Viewport meta is scaling your page to fit with client view port, for more information: [Viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).